# Rotating Object causes the size to change in Illustrator CS5

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I create a rectangle of size 200px X 200px. Select it, double click the rotate tool and rotate it at 45 degrees. This causes the rectangle to chage size and become 282.842px X 282.842px. How can I turnoff/disable this behavious maybe using the Preferences, or do I have to change it back to 200px X 200px by using the Tranform Panle.

[image: Rotate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size isn't changing.

Width and height readouts in the control bar and transform panel are calculated based on artboard perpendiculars (90° angles).

The distance from corner to corner of a 200px square is 282.842 pixels. The distance from side to side is 200pixels. When you rotate the square 45°, the width readout changes to indicate the new width, which is now from corner to corner.

If you want the width and height readout to remain constant, you could use Effects > Distort & Transform > Transform and enter 45 in the Angle field. It will rotate the square visually. This might make for difficult editing at times though.

Comment: Sorry but where is the control bar?

Comment: The bar across the top of the screen when Illustrator is the foreground app. - the one with the align buttons.. fill and stroke colors, style menu, etc.

Comment: Oh. But I don't see any width and height readouts there.

Comment: You would, if you had a larger monitor. :) Some fields only show themselves if there's room for them. Instead you get the "transform" panel link in their place.